# Как улучшить функцию

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```js
function replaceString(initString, strToReplace, replacer) {
  let result = initString;
  let i = 0;
  let len = strToReplace.length;
  while (len) {
    i = result.indexOf(strToReplace, i);
    if (i == -1) {
      break;
    }
    result = result.substring(0, i) + replacer + result.substring(i + len);
    i += len;
  }
  return result;
}
let newStr = replaceString("Я не люблю JavaScript", "не люблю", "люблю");
console.log(newStr)
```

Подскажите как улучшить эту функцию

Comment: а что делает эта функция? что конкретно хотелось бы улучшить

Comment: эта функция делает то же что и метод String.replace... Здесь у меня while (len) получается бесконечный цикл... не знаю как это изменить

Comment: @Анна `len` в цикле уменьшайте где-нибудь. Или условие цикла поменяйте.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n Так все работает и так, вопрос как сделать лучше.

Comment: @tilin так чуть выше спросили, _что конкретно_ хотелось бы сделать лучше, на что был получен ответ о бесконечном цикле. Ну или я под вечер уже ничего не понимаю.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n а как именно изменить условие цикла... у меня что то вообще нет идей :(

Comment: Может while на for заменить? он хотя бы закончится рано или поздно

Comment: @VladVetrov ну это еще смотря как постараться :D

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы не воспользоваться стандартной функцией [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?

```js
function replaceString(initString, strToReplace, replacer) {
  return initString.replace(strToReplace, replacer);
}

let newStr = replaceString("Я не люблю JavaScript", "не люблю", "люблю");
console.log(newStr)
```

Или если нужно заменить все "не люблю":

```js
function replaceString(initString, strToReplace, replacer) {
  return initString.replace(new RegExp(strToReplace, 'g'), replacer);
}

let newStr = replaceString("Я не люблю JavaScript", "не люблю", "люблю");
console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: в последнем случае нужно быть аккуратным - strToReplace может быть регулярным выражением, в котором будут интерпретироваться спец. символы

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем ясны цели и ограничения на собственную реализацию replace. Можно как один из вариантов рассмотреть вариант в котором сначала использовать функцию split, которая разделит строку, используя в качестве разделителя strToReplace. В результате получится массив в каждой ячейке которого будут последовательно лежать части строки без strToReplace:

```js
console.log("Я не люблю JavaScript и не люблю Василия".split("не люблю"));
```

а потом объединить этот массив в строку, используя функцию join. Которая возьмет все элементы массива и сделает из них строку, вставляя между элементами replacer.

Получится так:

```js
function replaceString(initString, strToReplace, replacer) {
    return initString.split(strToReplace).join(replacer);
}

console.log(replaceString("Я не люблю JavaScript и не люблю Василия", "не люблю", "люблю"));
```

Ну а что касается вашей реализации, то можно только косметически:

сделать len константой, потому что она никогда не изменяется

```
const len = strToReplace.length;
```

и сделать условие выполнения бесконечного цикла нормальным true

```
while (true) {
```

Comment: мне нужно именно функцией все зделать

Answer (score 0):

Ответ уже есть один, предложу свой вариант на основе идеи автора:

```
function replaceString(initString, strToReplace, replacer) {
  let result = initString;
  let i = 0;

  while ((i = result.indexOf(strToReplace, i)) != -1) {
    result = result.substring(0, i) + replacer
      + result.substring(i + strToReplace.length, result.length);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(replaceString('Я не люблю JavaScript', 'не люблю', 'люблю'));
console.log(replaceString('Тут нет таких слов', 'привет', 'пока'));
console.log(replaceString('Я люблю яблоки и яблоки', 'яблоки', 'девочек'));
```